# multiproject gradle build error: package does not exist

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio

I have some problems with building multiproject with gradle. I read all similar questions but nothing help. The structure of my projects looks like:

```
App/
    settings.gradle
    app/
        build.gradle
    libraries/
        Core(git submodule)/
            Core/
                build.gradle
            libraries/
                ZBarLibrary/
                    build.gradle
            settings.gradle
```

App/settings.gradle

```
include ':App', ':libraries:Core', ':libraries:ZBarLibrary'
project(':libraries:Core').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'libraries/Core/Core')
project(':libraries:ZBarLibrary').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'libraries/Core/libraries/ZBarLibrary')
```

App/app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:Core')
}
```

App/libraries/Core/Core/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    instrumentTestCompile "junit:junit:4.5+"
    compile project(':libraries:ZBarLibrary')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

App/libraries/Core/libraries/ZBarLibrary/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Command "gradle build" in App directory generates error: "package com… does not exist". This package is used in app module but it is find in App/libraries/Core/Core/src/main/java. Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Core as library you should change `apply plugin: 'android'` to `apply plugin: 'android-library'` in **App/libraries/Core/Core/build.gradle**

Comment: I noticed that there were no library. Moreover, setting directory for ZBarLibrary from setting.gradle does not work for me.

Comment: FYI I'm getting a message now that 'android-library' is now deprecated and you should use com.android.library

Answer (score 7):

Your app module's build.gradle should contain (among other things)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    compile project(':my_library_module')
}
```

Your library module's build.gradle file should contain

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem with Gradle 6.4 (multi-module project) and Java 13

Project structure:

```
app:
    backend:
        /src
        build.gradle
    base:
        /src
        build.gradle
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

Main class is contained in *base/build.gradle* and also *base-module* depends on *backend-module*.

**SOLUTION:** It is necessary to add following rows to *backend/build.gradle*

```
jar {
    enabled = true
}
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
```

and check that *base/build.gradle* has the following rows:

```
bootJar {
    archivesBaseName = 'base'
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(":backend")
}
```

Just in case, for newcomers in gradle put the listing of *settings.gradle file*:

```
rootProject.name = 'app'
include 'backend', 'base'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was the takeaway for me --> 
jar {
    enabled = true
}

Answer (score 4):

To resolve the package not found errors, in the `app` module's `build.gradle` file I added

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile project(':library')
}
```

which adds the `library` module as a dependency to the `app` module